# Induction: How do I simplify this expression to achieve a form (k+1)?

Tags: induction

As per comments, I've added the original question below (I'm new here, sorry!):
$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1&3^n - 1\\0&3^n\end{bmatrix}$$

for all integers n ≥ 1, where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to prove that n is true when n = k+1. I have figured out the base step. That leaves the recursive step. I made k+1 of the form

$$k+1 = A*A^n
= \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&3^n - 1\\0&3^n\end{bmatrix} $$

Multiplying the 2 matrices I get:

$$k+1
= \begin{bmatrix}1&3^n - 1 + 2*3^n\\0&3*3^n\end{bmatrix}
$$

I don't know how to go any further except to simplify the bottom-right term, where it becomes 3^(n+1)

Comment: You can't because they are not equal.  If you plug in $n=1$ the first gives $2+2\cdot 3=8$ and the second gives $(9-1)+2(9)=26$  Please check how you got here and correct the problem.

Comment: There is too little to help us here. It is certainly not the case that $(3^n - 1) + 2(3^n) = (3^{(n+1)} - 1) + 2(3^{(n+1)})$. If we are to help you, we will need to know more, in particular what you have tried.

Comment: $(3^n - 1) + 2 \cdot 3^n=3\cdot 3^n-1=3^{n+1}-1 \ne (3^{n+1}-1) + 2 \cdot 3^{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

The (*edit*: ***previously***) posted relation is wrong, what the induction proof actually needs is:
$$A^{n+1}=A^n \, A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3^n - 1\\0&3^n\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \cdot 1 + (3^n-1) \cdot 0 & 1 \cdot 2 + (3^n - 1) \cdot 3 \\ 0 \cdot 1 + 3^n \cdot 0 & 0 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 3^n\end{bmatrix}$$

For the top-right element, note that $\,2+(3^n-1)\cdot3 = 3 \cdot 3^n + 2 - 3 = 3^{n+1}-1\,$.

Comment: Have I arranged my multiplication incorrectly? It shouldn't be A^n+1 = A * A^n but A^n * A?

Comment: @HaneefMohdFairuz It doesn't matter, it's the same thing. The way you arranged it now (after the edit), look at my previous comment directly under your question. The end result is the same, either way.